# React Component Wrapper

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to wrap a non-react library and not succeeding.

After the javascript has been loaded, it has an init method where you name a DIV by ID so it attached to it, then later you can call destroy to remove it. I only want the init to be called when the component is loaded and destroy when it is unloaded, and I need access to make method calls on this library.

I have tried withEffect but it seems to get called every time state is set. That is where I had attempted to put the init call.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Library.init(...);    
    return function cleanup() {
        Library.destroy();
    }
}
```

What is the best practice for wrapping a library like this?

Comment: Have you tried to add an empty dependency array? `useEffect(()=>{...}, [])`

Comment: Brilliant! I did not know that existed. Thank you Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` runs by default every time the component renders.

If this is undesirable we can add a dependency array and the effect will only run when at least one of the dependencies has changed.

```
useEffect(()=>{...}, [])
```

By making it an empty dependency array, the effect will only run once when the component has mounted. The cleanup will also run only once when the component unmounts.